# Gimmett and Sitzaker Example 5 p 68

Tags: probability

There is a hen that lays N eggs,where N is Poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda$. K is the number of chicks hatched. They then show you how to calculate $f_{N|K}(n|k)$. I can follow most of the calculation but don't see how they get from the 2nd last line to the last line below?

$\begin{align}
 f_{N|K}(n|k)&= P(N=n |K=k) \\
 &= \frac{P(K=k |N=n)}{p(K=k)} \\
 &= \frac{\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}(\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda})}{\sum_{m \geq k}\binom{m}{k}p^k(1-p)^{m-k}(\frac{\lambda^m}{m!}e^{-\lambda})} \\
&= \frac{(q \lambda)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}e^{-q \lambda}
\end{align}$

Can someone please explain how this cancelling works?

Thanks

Baz

Comment: What is $i$?${}$

Comment: Grimmett and Stirzaker.

Comment: I presume $q=1-p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denominator is
$$
\frac1{k!} p^k\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}
\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{(1-p)^r\lambda^r}{r!}=
\frac1{k!} p^k\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}\exp((1-p)\lambda).
$$